# Multidimensional Array Filtering [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-filter

Im trying to filer out only parts of this array - by [channel] (like this):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [268a9d2d25fc2b9765c7cd7b8a768d3e] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => Emilian
                    [channel] => techno
                  )

            [5d1838c3aa6344e3109ab4f0122492f7] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => Emilian
                    [channel] => trance
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [e13268de7c56db42f8aeab2ab4c607f2] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => John Doe             
                    [channel] => trance

                )

            [1aa81b7b123321f79571828600db0f08] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => John Doe
                    [channel] => techno
                )

        )
```

So results should be (if channel is trance ) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [5d1838c3aa6344e3109ab4f0122492f7] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => Emilian
                    [channel] => trance
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [e13268de7c56db42f8aeab2ab4c607f2] => Array
                (
                    [dj_name] => John Doe             
                    [channel] => trance

                )


        )
```

... i have tried with foreach loops ... to unset but didnt have much succes .. also with array_filter ...

with foreach i tried like this ( but i dont know how to update the $show_data array once the loop is closed ... hmm im pretty green at php:

```
foreach($show_data as $idindex => $codearray){
            foreach($codearray as $codestring => $paramarray) {       
                        foreach($paramarray as $param => $val) {    
                                if(preg_grep('/trance/', $paramarray)){
                                     unset($paramarray[$val]);
                                  }}}}
        print_r($show_data);
```

And I also tried with ( but if the first one is trance then it doesnt filter out the rest.. even if they are techno ... i need it to filter out at the [5d1838c3aa6344e3109ab4f0122492f7] level ) :

```
$genre = 'trance';
$data = array_filter($dataraw, function($fs) use ($genre) {
 return current($fs)['channel'] === $genre;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `if(preg_grep('/trance/', $val)){`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it will hepl you.

```
$output_array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($show_data as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $subdata) {
        if ($subdata['channel'] == 'trance') {
            $output_array[$i] = $subdata;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output_array);
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
  $result = [];
        foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
                foreach($val as $k=>$v){
                    if($v['channel']=='trance'){
                        $result[$k] = $v;
                    }
                }
        }

  echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [5d1838c3aa6344e3109ab4f0122492f7] => Array
        (
            [dj_name] => Emilian
            [channel] => trance
        )

    [e13268de7c56db42f8aeab2ab4c607f2] => Array
        (
            [dj_name] => John Doe
            [channel] => trance
        )

)
```